# Naive implementation for tenant isolation in shared DB

Tags: typescript, nestjs, multi-tenant, typeorm, saas

I am trying to build an MVP for a SaaS product that realizes tenant isolation. I want to achieve this while using one database and one schema (isolation by application logic only). Achieving this is surprisingly hard! Simply hoping that I won't forget to add the necessary `WHERE` condition on every query is too error-prone. I have tried some approaches and landed on a very naive implementation:

- Extract the tennantId with middleware from the request and make it globally available.
- Use simple typeORM listeners `AfterLoad` `BeforeInsert` etc. to perform additional checks.

```typescript
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    uuid: string

    @Column({ default: 'tenant-1' })
    tenantId: string;

    @AfterLoad()
    checkTenant() {
        if(this.tenantId !== getCurrentTenant()) { <-- get globally available tenantId
            throw new BadRequestException('This data is outside your organization')
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I would put the Listener logic in a base class and have all models inherit from it.

**Is this approach problematic? Will it be problematic once the app scales and I'm querying e.g. 6000 users at once?**

Comment: I don't have the answer for you unfortunately, but multi-tenancy is something I want to implement in a future project. I found [ultimate-backend](https://github.com/juicycleff/ultimate-backend) as a full-blown SaaS starter that uses NestJS. It is a complex app but it may help you.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, ultimate-backend uses a multi-db approach using MongoDB. That's not really the approach I was looking for.

Comment: @Xen_mar Hi, did you find answer to your question? Mind sharing if you got some information in this regard? Thanks.

Comment: No, sorry. I switched away from NestJS and implemented it in Django.